# Subtract first row from each row and compute the relative differences

Tags: pgfplotstable

I am trying to create a new column from another one by subtracting from each row the first one. Then I want to create another column with the relative difference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
TotalDistance
35089
35182
35410
35523
35694
35789
35895
35984
36006
36068
}{\mytable}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns={TotalDistance,LocalDistance},
    create on use/LocalDistance/.style={
        create col/expr={\thisrow{TotalDistance} - 35089},
    },
    create on use/DifferenceDistance/.style={
        create col/expr={\thisrow{LocalDistance} - \prevrow{LocalDistance}},
    },
    ]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```

My goal is to obtain:

```
  TD  | LD  | DD
------+-----+----
35089 |   0 |   0
35182 |  93 |  93
35410 | 321 | 228
35523 | 434 | 113
35694 | 605 | 171
35789 | 700 |  95
35895 | 806 | 106
35984 | 895 |  89
36006 | 917 |  22
36068 | 979 |  62
```

The problems so far are:

1. How to avoid to hardcode `35089`, but instead read it from the first cell?
2. I get errors *Unknown function `LocalDistance__column_not_found'* when I try to typeset the column DifferenceDistance, even if the column LocalDistance would be created without problems.

Comment: You need to get the LD row in place to be able to refer to `\prevrow`. You can use `\pgfplotstablecreatecol` instead.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can read the first cell value with `\pgfplotstablegetelem{<row>}{<col>}\of\mytable`. The return value will be written to `\pgfplotsretval`.
2. As proposed by *percusse*, here is an example using `\pgfplotstablecreatecol` instead of `\pgfplotstabletypeset` to add columns to the table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
TotalDistance
35089
35182
35410
35523
35694
35789
35895
35984
36006
36068
}{\mytable}

% read the first cell value -> \pgfplotsretval
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{TotalDistance}\of\mytable

% add column LocalDistance
\pgfplotstablecreatecol
    [expr={\thisrow{TotalDistance} - \pgfplotsretval}]
    {LocalDistance}{\mytable}

% add column DifferenceDistance
\pgfplotstablecreatecol
    [expr={\thisrow{LocalDistance} - \prevrow{LocalDistance}}]
    {DifferenceDistance}{\mytable}

% typeset the table
\pgfplotstabletypeset
    [columns={TotalDistance,LocalDistance,DifferenceDistance}]
    {\mytable}

\end{document}
```